# Change of State

Tags: thermodynamics

The following is known about a change of state: Closed system, ideal gas, density remains constant. It is a matter of

1. isochoric
2. isentropic change of state
3. isobaric change of state
4. isothermal change of state

I would say isochoric, because it is a closed system and the mass must remain constant ...
so density = mass / volume => if density is constant then volume must be constant too.

What do you say ?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: processes are defined by what they are, not by what you call them.  You tell us what it is.

Comment: this was a question i should choose if it is 1,2,3 or 4 and i would say 4

Comment: Think about what each of the isxxxxxx terms mean and choose one that maintains the density of the gas. Example: isothermal means pressure can change, isobaric means temperature can change, isentropic means only entropy is constant, etc.